# Force a file to overwrite instead of appending

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, file

I've got an application that won't overwrite a file with the same filename. It will only append the filename with a 'space 1'. If I write a file more than once I get something like this:

- filename.jpg
- filename 1.jpg
- filename 2.jpg

What I need is to only ever have the newest file without the extra space and number.

Is there anyway around this? Perhaps an applescript running in the folder?

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: Capture One from Phase One.

Comment: Does anyone know what this phenomenon is called?

Comment: Cross-posted ([tsk, tsk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)) to SU as [#254915](http://superuser.com/questions/254915/force-a-file-to-overwrite-instead-of-appending-the-filename).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application is in complete control of how it saves files (overwrite v. append). The answer is to pre-clean your destination before you start whatever work flow you are doing in Capture One. There are any number of ways to accomplish that.

- use the `rm` command from the terminal
- write a bash script that does something more complicated
- write an applescript
- create a new folder each time to point the application at
- create a disk image via Disk Utility that you can clone and throw away when finished

These are just some of the ideas. I am sure there are other ways as well. Just need to find one that works for you.

A final thought, contact the makers of Capture One and make a case for why you would like them to change the software. Perhaps they will listen. :)

Good luck.